# Android - как убрать полосу под заголовком в приложении

Tags: android

Изучаю потихоньку Android, столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу точно описать.

В главном активити есть один заголовок и под ним есть ещё какая-то пока неизвестная мне строка.

При запуске приложения она также отрисовывается.

Если попытаться убрать заголовок, указав в манифесте AppTheme.NoActionBar, то уберётся только строчка с Sample, а нижняя пустая так и останется.

[image: заголовок]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это и как это убрать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего это `Toolbar`. Если это так, то, поскольку оба эти виджета выполняют сходные задачи, вам нужно сделать нелегкий выбор - использовать `ActionBar` или `Toolbar`

В первом случае вам нужно убрать из кода и разметки использование `Toolbar`, во втором использовать тему без `ActionBar` (с NoActionBar в конце темы), а `Toolbar` назначить исполняющим функции `ActionBar`-а:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //id тулбара в разметке
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Со своей стороны замечу, что `Toolbar` более гибкий и управляемый элемент, чем `ActionBar`

В любом случае вы должны посмотреть свою разметку для данной активити и там вы увидите, что это. Ничего такого, что вы туда сами не помещали, там быть не может.